# Pure NativeScript migrate to Angular or Vue

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-angular, nativescript-vue

I have a project with pure nativescript core, in JS. Is there any way to migrate this project to Vue or Angular in an automated way or little by little?

Thank you;

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about Angular but I don't think so.

As for Vue there is no such thing, they are too different, a Vue components has a particular structure; I suppose it is the same for Angular.